# Identify the First and Last Enquiry Source on the Contact object

Tags: formula, formula-field, custom-field, custom

I have a custom object called "Enquiries" when someone enquires in the enquiry is created as well as a Contact. You can have multiple Enquiries linked to a contact.

Within the contact there is a field called "Enquiry Source" indicating the marketing source the enquiry came from. I am wanting to create a field within the Contact object that indicates the Enquiry Source from the first enquiry and the then another field that indicates the enquiry source from the latest enquiry.

Can anyone help with how i can achieve this please ?

Comment: You can do this with the free Declarative lookup Rollup Summaries tool.  https://dandonin.com/2017/03/16/how-to-dlrs/

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is impossible to do with a formula field alone.

Formula fields can travel upwards in a relationship hierarchy (so, you could have a formula on `Enquiry__c` that pulls data from `Contact`), but not downwards.

As you said, a `Contact` can have multiple `Enquiry__c` records related to it. Formula fields do not have the ability to process multiple "child" records, nor can we say something like "pick the first record and use that".

Process Builder might work here, but my instinct would be to create a trigger for this. You should head over to https://trailhead.salesforce.com to learn more about those if you're not already familiar with them.